# Groovy : groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: groovy

I'm just starting with groovy. This error looks basic. but i don't seem to get through this. Appreciate any help in guiding me through the right direction

I'm defining a string like below and passing it to testSender method

```
def line = "5 1 -81.42 Ido1"
testSender(line.toString())
```

Definition of testSender method

```
def testSender(line){
     try {
         println line  
     } catch(e) {
         println e.printStackTrace()
     }
}
```

When I run this, getting this error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: GroovySQLQuery$_main_closure1.testSender() 
is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [5 1 -81.42 Ido1]
```

Comment: Main point to note is `GroovySQLQuery$_main_closure1.testSender()`. Why `GroovySQLQuery` is referred for `testSender()` where testSender is just a test method which you implemented.

Comment: Name of the script is GroovySQLquery.groovy. testSender is a method part of this script

Comment: please provide a complete example, that shows the error.  putting that code into a groovy file runs fine

Comment: class GroovySQLQuery{
  static void main(String[] args) 
  {
                    def line = "5 1 -81.42 Ido1"
                    testSender(line.toString())
  }
  
   def testSender(line)
     {
        println line 
     }
 
}

Comment: that is the whole script.... here is the exception..... groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static GroovySQLQuery.testSender() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [5 1 -81.42 Ido1]
Possible solutions: testSender(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
class GroovySQLQuery { 
    static void main(String[] args) { 
        def line = "5 1 -81.42 Ido1" 
        testSender(line.toString()) 
    } 

    static testSender(line) { 
        println line 
    } 
}
```