# How to execute 'aws ecr get-login' inside Groovy script

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy

Still trundling through my first ever Groovy scripts and I've hit another snag. I'm converting Jenkins 2 freestyle jobs over to pipeline jobs and I can't find the equivalent for `eval $(aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1)` in Groovy.

Research suggests the solution should be something like `Eval.me('aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1')` but this causes the following error;

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test2.node() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, test2$_run_closure1) values: [on-demand-t2small, test2$_run_closure1@1a04f701]
Possible solutions: notify(), wait(), run(), run(), dump(), grep()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test2.node() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, test2$_run_closure1) values: [on-demand-t2small, test2$_run_closure1@1a04f701]
Possible solutions: notify(), wait(), run(), run(), dump(), grep()
```

I've googled the error but the resulting stackoverflow answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411209/how-to-fix-groovy-lang-missingmethodexception-no-signature-of-method) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369978/groovy-groovy-lang-missingmethodexception-no-signature-of-method) are so specific to their cases that I, as a Groovy noob, can't understand the solution. Any help (with explanations of why that's the solution) is appreciated.

I don't know if the rest of my script is relevant; if so please let me know and I can edit to add it.

Comment: Your question title doesn't reflect the question you are actually asking. You aren't looking for an alternative for that AWS CLI command, you are looking for the proper way to execute a shell command from Groovy. If you actually wanted an alternative to that AWS CLI command in Groovy then you would need to look into using the AWS SDK for Java.

Comment: Also note that the error message `No signature of method: test2.node()` doesn't seem related to the code you've included in your question. I think your error is on a different line of code.

Comment: @MarkB My bad for the poor phrasing, I'll edit and fix that. Do you happen to have a solution? I suppose I am looking to execute a shell command in Groovy.

Comment: @MarkB I would agree with you except that I am running an identical script (minus the aws line) alongside this one, with no problems. It's only with the introduction of the aws line that things break. It's totally possible that there's something else wrong but the current issue seems to be the aws bit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **run** the `docker login` command, which is returned by `aws ecr get-login`, not evaluate **Groovy** code, which is what [Eval](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) does.

A minimal example:

```
def ecrLogin = "aws ecr get-login".execute()
ecrLogin.waitFor()

def dockerLogin = ecrLogin.text.execute()
dockerLogin.waitFor()

println dockerLogin.text
```

Note, that you should add some error handling on top of it, as this code is fairly optimistic about **Docker** and **AWS** availability.